# How can I prevent the AT&T update software from using my 4G connection?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, att

Is there any way to prevent the AT&T update software form using my 4G connection (i.e. using Wi-Fi only when available)?

By default it seems to use the 4G connection when there's no Wi-Fi connection, as the screenshots below show. I use Samsung I9300 Galaxy S III with a rooted Android 4.1.2.

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

Following saloalv's answer, I tapped on "Android OS" (which is the process listed as being the one who used my 4G connection): I don't see any "restrict background data" option.

[image]

[image]

I do see the "restrict background data"  option for other processes though:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open data usage in settings, tap on AT&T software update, scroll down and tap "restrict background data".

Comment: Thanks. I added 3 screenshots at the end of my answer: I don't see the "restrict background data" option for Android OS (where AT&T software update seems to be somehow encapsulated) :/

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt seems that either this is part of android design, and system apps don't have that setting, or AT&T did something to make sure you can't restrict background data. This procedure would have worked for an user app though